# PyQT Connecting lambda function to Signal

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm stuck with the following problem. I'm trying to connect a lambda function to a Signal for passing some extra data eventually.

```
def createTimeComboBox(self,slotCopy):
    timeComboBox = QComboBox()

    #...

    cmd = lambda func=self.test:func()
    self.connect(timeComboBox, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"),cmd)

#...

def test(self, value):
    print value
```

When I run `createTimeComboBox(),` I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Changing

```
self.connect(timeComboBox, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"),cmd)
```

to

```
self.connect(timeComboBox, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"),self.test)
```

works fine, but I would like to be able to pass the `slotCopy` variable as well, so assumed that I need to use the `lambda` approach.

I had done this previously with a `QPushButton`'s `clicked()` signal and that worked fine.

```
def createToDoctorButton(self,extraData):
    toDoctorButton = QPushButton()

    cmd = lambda func=self.goToDoctor:func(extraData)
    self.connect(toDoctorButton,  SIGNAL('clicked()'),cmd)

    return toDoctorButton

def goToDoctor(self,extraData):
    print extraData
```

I hope this makes sense - does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for any suggestions!
Cheers
Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `lambda` accepts a parameter (`func`):

```
lambda func=self.test:func()
```

Although the parameter has a default, it will be replaced if a parameter is passed. Looking at the signal, `currentIndexChanged(int)`, shows that the signal will pass an integer parameter. `func` will be the integer coming from `currentIndexChanged`. Later, doing `func()` will be effectively trying to call an integer object which obviously is not legal (as the error indicates)

You need another parameter in your `lambda` to "catch" the passed parameter without overriding the `func` parameter:

```
cmd = lambda value, func=self.test: func(value)
```

By the way, your `test` method expects a parameter, so you can't just do `func()`.

You didn't have that problem with the `clicked()` signal because it doesn't pass a parameter to replace the default value.

Comment: Plus from me, how did you know the Parameter was overwritten?

Comment: @user1767754 by the way signals work in Qt. Slots can have same or fewer arguments and the extra ones will be ignored. But the remaining ones will be passed. It doesn't matter if you have a default for that argument or not. If a signal passes an argument, slot will receive it if it can.

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for you:

```
timeComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.test)
```

Here is a small working example, demonstrating new style signals/slots connection with and without lambdas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems([str(x) for x in range(3)])
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        slotLambda = lambda: self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged_lambda("some_value")
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(slotLambda)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, value):
        print value

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged_lambda(self, string):
        print string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I haven't managed to go through this yet, but will get around to it later today hopefully!