# Passing parameters to a slot function using lambda

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, lambda

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__();
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("print clicked",self)
        self.clicked='not_clicked'
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda opt='clicked': self.option(opt)) 

    def option(self,opt):
        self.clicked=opt
        print opt



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Consider this code. Now, when I click the 'print clicked' button. 'False' get printed( in the option function). Why is this happening?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14176578/843822).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QPushButton` inherits the signal `clicked` from `QAbstractButton`.
Qt documentation states:

> void QAbstractButton::clicked ( bool **checked = false** ) [signal]
>
> This signal is emitted when the button is activated (i.e. pressed down then released while the mouse cursor is inside the button), when the shortcut key is typed, or when click() or animateClick() is called. Notably, this signal is not emitted if you call setDown(), setChecked() or toggle().
>
> If the button is **checkable**, checked is true if the button is checked, or false if the button is unchecked.

The argument the slot received indicates whether the button is checked. Since `QPushButton` is by default **not** checkable. the argument is always `False`. That is why 'False' got printed.

If you want the print result varies, printing 'True' or 'False', you can either set the button `checkable` or change it to `QCheckBox`.
For example, `initUI` should be

```
def initUI(self):
    self.button = QtGui.QCheckBox("print clicked",self)
    self.button.setCheckable(True)
    self.clicked='not_clicked'
    self.button.clicked.connect(lambda opt='clicked': self.option(opt))
```

or

```
def initUI(self):
    #self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("print clicked",self)
    self.button = QtGui.QCheckBox("print clicked",self)
    self.clicked='not_clicked'
    self.button.clicked.connect(lambda opt='clicked': self.option(opt))
```